# How to run nodejs project in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on Nodejs and right now i am trying to run nodejs project (existing) , how can i do this ? Here is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.js,.md -c .eslintrc.json --fix",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "dev": "next dev",
  },
```

I tried with following code but not working,How can i do this ?

```
npm jest
```

Comment: Are you working on node or nextjs ?

Answer (score 2):

First clean this up

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.js,.md -c .eslintrc.json --fix",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "dev": "next dev" // notice i removed the trailing comma here
  },
```

Once that is set, run your commands

To start your project

```
npm run dev
```

To run your tests

```
npm run test
```

The idea is basically `npm run [script]`

Answer (score 1):

To run your project:

```
npm run dev
```

To run unit tests:

```
npm run test
```

Comment: but i am getting following error " Unexpected token } in JSON at position 375 while parsing near '...dev": "next dev""

Comment: @user2332: JSON doesn't allow trailing commas. Remove `,` after `"next dev"` (and in the rest of the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your scripts in the terminal with the `npm run [script]` command. In your case, run `npm run test`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any scripts. It has to be defined in package.json file
For example define your package.json as shown below:

```
"scripts" :{
     "start": "node index.js",
      "test" : "mocha test/**.spec.ts"
}
Once it's defined you can run
npm run start -> to start up your server
npm run test -> to run unit test using mocha(just an example)
```